# URL Rewrite on Windows 2016 (IIS 10) with .Net Core to point to CDN

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-rewrite-module, iis-10

I have a brand new virtual server running Windows 2016 (IIS 10).   I have a website that is built with .NET Core 1.1.

I would like to rewrite all image, js, font, and css references to point to a CDN.

**Problem 1**, adding this rule:

```
<rule name="CDN Assets" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^css/(.+)$|^images/(.+)$|^fonts/(.+)$|^js/(.+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://cdn.example.net/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

... results in a 404 for every request.   For example a request to https://example.net/images/en-us/logo.png even though the image exists both in the real folder under and at https://cdn.example.net/images/en-us/logo.png

Is this possibly caused by .NET Core or by HTTP2 (which is introduced in IIS 10).   Or do I need some sort of outbound rule also?

**Problem 2**, adding an outbound rule like:

```
<rule name="Outbound CDN: images" preCondition="IsHtml">
    <match filterByTags="A, Img, Link" pattern="^/images/(.+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="//cdn.example.net{R:0}" />
</rule>
<preConditions>
    <preCondition name="IsHtml">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html"/>
    </preCondition>
</preConditions>
```

Causes the page response to become complete mangled unreadable garbage.   Is this because of the response is sent over HTTPS?

---

**UPDATE (2016/03/16 8:01PM MST)**

Using @EricB suggestion I have tried implementing it via the Microsoft.ASPNetCore.Rewrite package to no avail.

I have this in my *Startup.cs* and just the local images are being loaded:

```
string CDNroot = Configuration["URLs:CDN"].Trim();
RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^(css|images|fonts|js)(.+)$", CDNroot + "/$1$2", skipRemainingRules: true);
app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

If I change this to:

```
string CDNroot = Configuration["URLs:CDN"].Trim();
RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect(@"^(css|images|fonts|js)(.+)$", CDNroot + "/$1$2");
app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

... and request an image URL it is correctly *redirected* to the CDN URL.   But you wouldn't want a redirect, as that is adding an extra 30x response to every asset request.   I am stumped why Redirect works, but Rewrite doesn't.

Comment: I think you  need the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware) package for this

Comment: @EricB see my update above.

Comment: Redirect works because you are telling the client to fetch from a different host. Rewrite won't work because it will just try to rewrite to a different route in your own api. If you really don't want to redirect the client, you'll need to proxy the request on the server side. Either way, the HTTP request will get made somewhere.

Comment: @EricB The CDN has it's own host name.  I am assigning it to the variable CDNroot which gets prepended to the rewrite destination path.  Why would this try to rewrite to a different route in my own api?   Just confused I guess.   If nothing else how would I "proxy the request on the server side", as it seems it would be much more efficient from a network latency standpoint to do it right at the server.

Comment: You can proxy requests with a middleware such as [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/ProxyMiddleware.cs) or a mvc routing rule. Either way you will need to make the http request in code using an HttpClient. I'd try this instead if the Rewriter can't do what you need. The real solution is to just send the request to the CDN directly from the client without your server acting as a middle man.